# Use php to send an automatic email on a button securely/no spam

Tags: php, javascript, spam, spam-prevention

I'm creating a web page for a kiosk at a building entrance, so there will be 4 buttons on one page with each department's name on. Everytime when a button is clicked, an email will be sent to an appropriate department email address to inform a visitor is here.

I posted another related question, someone said there will be a security hole there, because the departments will get a lot of spams since this is going to be hosted on my company's subdomain. What is the best way to overcome it? Can I use some php code to fix the spam issue?

Any code or useful links would be appreciated.

Here is the code I'm using at the moment, I can change it entirely if you have some better suggestions. Thanks.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="Send details to A" />
<input type="hidden" name="button_a" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_a']))
{

$to      = 'name@ourcompany.com'; 

$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@ourcompany.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

Comment: As long as its kiosk accessible only, I don't see any big spam issue here, apart from the kids "playing" with all the buttons.

Comment: *"since this is going to be hosted on my company's subdomain"* ... If it's hosted on the company's subdomain and it's not behind a password wall, this is prime spammable real estate.

Comment: I was thinking you could have the PHP code check the IP address of the remote host, if it is not the IP/subnet that the kiosk in the lobby uses, reject the request and don't send the email.  I don't really see any spam issues here though.  Make sure that the mail server the PHP script uses is configured correctly (i.e. PTR records for its IP address)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing you can do is find out the IP address of the Kiosk and only allow that.

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $ip_of_kiosk) exit;
```

Comment: Note here that you'd need to ensure the Kiosk IP is static and won't change.

Answer (score 2):

This is very true, an e-mail address in plain text that is readable by any robot (in particular Google) will be picked up by spammers very quickly.

A few approaches: Deal with the spam somehow. Certainly not the preferred option with many cons to it's few pro's. Not to mention the potential cost to the business.

Second approach, embed the email address in an image. This is how Facebook usually display email addresses within the native FB gui.

Third approach, obfuscate the e-mail address within your code and only allow your scripts access to the salt for decryption when sending the email.

Last but not least, this comment applies to all the above: make sure your `robots` file clearly stops standard SE bots digging any further into your application than it need do further reducing the risk of the addresses being virally pumped into the public domain.